# Working tested javascript doesn't work when running from Google Sheets html template

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets, dropdown

I'm very very new to scripting in general, so please bear with me.

I am testing some scripts on google sheets, running an HTML template.

Part of my script requires calling on array data. I am testing running this script: http://jsfiddle.net/nExgJ/

You will see that the script runs as desired.

However, when the HTML template launches from Google Sheets, even with the same code, the numbers are not populated.

In Google Sheets script, the following function is used to run the HTML template:

```
  var htmlDlg = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setWidth(500)
      .setHeight(150);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .showModalDialog(htmlDlg, 'Select An Existing Client');
}
```

I also have a doGet function in place, which is as follows:

```
function doGet() {
 var htmlOutput = template.evaluate()
                   .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
  return htmlOutput;
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}
```

Then the code in my HTML form is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <script>
    // Get dropdown element from DOM
var dropdown = document.getElementById("selectNumber");

// Loop through the array
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
    // Append the element to the end of Array list
    dropdown[dropdown.length] = new Option(myArray[i], myArray[i]);
}

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<form id="myForm">
  <select id="selectNumber">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
  </select>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

[the actual result when code is run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHF7y.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### In Apps Script you can implement this functionality by using [scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets)

The advantage of scriptlets is that you can also incorporate data from your spreadsheet or variables from `Code.gs` into your options.

Sample:

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm">
  <select id="selectNumber">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
    <? var myArray = new Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");?>
    <? for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) { ?>
     <option> <?=myArray[i]?> </option>
     <? } ?>
  </select>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

*Code.gs*

```
function myFunction() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');  
  var htmlDlg = template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setWidth(500)
  .setHeight(150);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .showModalDialog(htmlDlg, 'Select An Existing Client');
}
```

> UPDATE:

**If you prefer to use your script, you have to move it from head to body, after the rest of your html content.**

This allows you to render the HTML content (basically create a  element with the id "selectNumber") before you modify the contents of this html with Javascript, see [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#load_javascript_last).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you clarify if code.gs is the scripting area of Google Sheets? Like I said I'm very new :D

Comment: If someone could also explain why my existing code didn't work without scriptlets, that would be really great :)

Comment: I updated my answer to explain why your script did not work - basically it is about the position where you inserted the Javascript.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help :)